# Spring RequestMappping not working

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

i am trying to call controller with link, but its not working all annotation configuration and url pattern is metioned in configuration file. here is my code

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!-- Scan only for @Controllers -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" use-default-filters="false" >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->


<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

html :

```
 <a href="hi.htm">Call controller</a>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public ModelAndView add(){
        System.out.println("in");
        return new ModelAndView("demo", "message", "Add method called");
    }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you trying, and what is your WAR name?  If you are deploying to a container as a WAR, then you typically have to include that as the first part of your URI.  If you are deploying using embeded Tomcat, Jetty, etc then that's a different story, but since you have a web.xml I would assume you are not.

Comment: try to change this <a href="hi">Call controller</a>

Comment: It is working, I tested your App, The only thing missing your case do you have View Resolver for demo (You need a folder jsp, in this path (/WEB-INF/jsp/demo.jsp). If you have it then it should work. You just need to access the page http://host:port/appcontext/hi.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was using `import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView`. 
i changed it to `import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView`.